# Angular stop listening to EventEmitter after error

Tags: angular, error-handling, event-handling

I have a merge listening to a couple of events and retrieving data in response from a service, if the service throws an error the events are no longer listened to - at least so it seems since debugging the events show they fire and also other components that listen to them respond. I am assuming this is a result of the error, but since I have a catch error I can't figure out why this happens.

Here is a simplified code example:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    merge(event1, event2)
         .pipe(
             switchMap(event => {
                 return this.service.loadResults()
                     .pipe(catchError(() => {
                         return observableOf([]);
                     }));
             }))
             .subscribe(data => {
                this.entityList = data;
             });
}
```

Other attempts that did not help:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    merge(event1, event2)
      .pipe(
        switchMap(event => {
          return this.service.loadResults();
        })).pipe(
          catchError(() => {
            return observableOf([]);
          })
        )
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.entityList = data;
      });
}
```

And:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    merge(event1, event2)
     .pipe(
         switchMap(event => {
             return this.service.loadResults();
         }),
         catchError(() => {
                return observableOf([]);
            }))
         .subscribe(data => {
            this.entityList = data;
         });
}
```

Comment: Did you console log to make sure it is executed this line return observableOf([]);?

Comment: It executed once on the first error.

Answer (score 0):

That's how RxJS `switchMap` works. It will unsubscribe from the `Observable` returned by its `project` argument as soon as it has invoked the `project` function again to produce a new `Observable`.

Use `mergeMap` instead.

#### Reference:

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap#description

> When a new inner Observable is emitted, switchMap stops emitting items from the earlier-emitted inner Observable and begins emitting items from the new one. It continues to behave like this for subsequent inner Observables.

Comment: 1. I want to keep my `switchMap` since it allows me cancel previews requests. 2. This does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I test it in stackbliz.com, it worked when I am throw error manually, but I think it's the same throw error from service. Here is the demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gvvwbb?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
merge(this.event1, this.event2)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(event => {
      return throwError("error").pipe(
        catchError(() => {
          return of(
            event.target["innerHTML"] === "event1 div"
              ? "catch error from div 1"
              : "catch error from div 2"
          );
        })
      );
    })
  )
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log("data = ", data);
  });
```